# How can I remove a sub-query from a NOT EXISTS contained in an INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Due to rules set forward by third party software I need to remove the sub-query from the following code:

```
SELECT
1
FROM 
factAttempt fact
INNER JOIN dimActivity act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
INNER JOIN dimUser emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
INNER JOIN Iwc_Usr IUser ON IUser.Usr_empFK = emp.EmpFK
INNER JOIN dimActivity class ON (
    (class.ActivityFK = act.PrntActFK)
    OR (
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM TBL_TMX_activity act1
            WHERE act1.PrntActFK = Class.ActivityFK
        )

        AND 
            Class.ActivityFK = act.ActivityFK
        )
    )
    AND class.ActivityName = act.ActivityName
```

I have tried using a Boolean (bit) scalar variable to replace it but while it will run the wrong results are returned. Since I don't know too much SQL I haven't been able to find anything else yet.
I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 if that's useful

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the `exists` table to a `left join`. Then the equivalent to the `not exists` is checking that the value of a field in the right part of the join is null.

```
SELECT
1
FROM 
factAttempt fact
INNER JOIN dimActivity act ON act.ID = fact.ActivityID
INNER JOIN dimUser emp ON emp.ID = fact.UserID
INNER JOIN Iwc_Usr IUser ON IUser.Usr_empFK = emp.EmpFK
INNER JOIN dimActivity class 
    LEFT JOIN TBL_TMX_activity act1 
    ON act1.PrntActFK = class.ActivityFK
ON 
(
    (
      class.ActivityFK = act.PrntActFK
      OR 
      (act1.PrntActFK IS NULL -- equivalent of NOT EXISTS
        AND Class.ActivityFK = act.ActivityFK)
    )
    AND class.ActivityName = act.ActivityName
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that returns the error 'The multi-part identifier "Class.ActivityFK" could not be bound.'
I think this is because the LEFT JOIN uses class before class is defined and added in the following INNER JOIN.

Comment: Yep... I modified the query (I was trying to join to a table which wasn't joined beforehand) SO I have needed to nest the JOINS